# get classPage name ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I would like to identify the class page name in ionic 3.

```
class MyClassPage {}

console.log(this.instance.constructor.name); // MyClassPage
console.log(MyClassPage.name); // MyClassPage
```

This not work when running from a minified file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
this.navCtrl.getActive().id
```